# Polymer "webcomponentsjs": `"MutationObserver" undefined` error in IE9

Tags: polymer, internet-explorer-9, babeljs

Compiling all files from the https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs project down to IE9 Javascript using Babel, IE11 in IE9 compatibility mode reports `"MutationObserver" undefined` error in the console.

How can I have this compile?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, It looks like **MutationObserver** is only supported in IE 11 version.

[image]

So this can be the cause for the issue.

I suggest you to use IE 11 as it is and do not use IE 9 document mode in it to avoid this issue.

Reference:

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)